# Accessing WCF webservice using browser

Tags: c#, wcf

How to access WCF webservice using browser?
Currently its just implemented as normal webservice.
Please let me know how to set webConfig settings as well.

Comment: what do you mean by "access WCF webservice using browser" ?

Comment: To test the service via Browser url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access and test your WCF service from within your browser, you will need to make it RESTFUL webservice.

here are a couple of resources that will help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/344512/Building-and-Testing-WCF-RESTful-services

also checkout this nice article that sums the needs and various aspects of building RESTFUL web services 
http://predic8.com/rest-webservices.htm